# Ruby method returning as "undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby

Creating a rock, paper, scissors game with randomisation and a rule engine but the `winner_is` method seems to be returning nil. I can't really figure out what the variables within it are returning since it still prints them fine before all the if conditions.

```
class RPS

    def initialize(guess:)  
        @guess = guess.capitalize
    end        

    def rule_engine 
        {
            'Rock': ['Scissors'],
            'Paper': ['Rock'],
            'Scissors': ['Paper']
        }
    end

    def sys_guess
        rand 12345
        sys_guesses = %w{Rock Paper Scissors}
        sys_guesses.sample
    end

    def winner_is 
         puts sys_guess
         puts @guess

        if rule_engine[sys_guess.to_sym].include? @guess
           puts "Computer wins"
         elsif rule_engine[@guess.to_sym].include? sys_guess
           puts "You win!"
         else
           puts "Tie"
         end
    end
end

rps = RPS.new(guess: gets)
rps.winner_is
```

Comment: `rule_engine` returns hash with keys of type 'string`, but `rule_engine[sys_guess.to_sym]` passing key of type `symbol`(integer)

Comment: @Fabio Correct me if I'm wrong but I was told the hash I written returned symbols? But yeah, I guess it makes sense. How do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: Remove `.to_sym`

Comment: @Fabio Unfortunately, I already tried that and it still results in the same error.

Comment: @Fabio: "rule_engine returns hash with keys of type 'string`" - nope, those keys are symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

> ```
>  rps = RPS.new(guess: gets)
> ```

The string you get from `gets` includes a trailing newline. Naturally, *this* key is not found in your hash, even with `.to_sym`. Trim the newline with `.chomp`, for example.

---

I get the feeling that you actually wanted to use string keys. If so, this would be the syntax:

```rb
    def rule_engine 
        {
            'Rock' => ['Scissors'],
            'Paper' => ['Rock'],
            'Scissors' => ['Paper']
        }
    end
```

Comment: Ah, that certainly got rid of that error. Thanks a ton! However, I'm getting some inconsistent logic errors in terms of output. I can't quite tell where the issue is but it has something to do with the two data types being compared? Even when scissors should beat paper, it gives me a tie.

Comment: @Lazlo: yeah, this is when I heavily decorate my code with debug printing, to help me figure out if variables do actually hold the values I expect them to.

Comment: @Lazlo: ah, I see it. Actually, your existing debug output should be enough to detect the issue. Try to solve this one by yourself, add more printing if you need. Come back later if absolutely stuck.

Comment: For sure, I appreciate any and all help. I apologise if I come across as inexperienced, still pretty new to this gig.

Comment: No need to apologize for that! We've all been there.

Comment: Alright, I'm stumped. It's been several hours and I've taken breaks on and off trying to walk it over but I don't get it. I feel like it's blatantly obvious but it genuinely isn't coming to me.

Comment: @Lazlo: you're good, it's not obvious at all. In your `winner_is` you're calling `sys_guess` several times. BUT it returns a random value each time! So you print one value, check another value if it beats user input and check if yet another value (third) is beaten by user input. As you noticed, this gives very unpredictable results. Make sure to only call `sys_guess` once. Or memoize its value if this instance of `RPS` is not to be reused for another game.

Comment: @Lazlo: I was actually wrong about "your existing debug output should be enough to detect the issue". I thought your `capitalize` was `upcase`. So I had to copy your code and insert more debug printing.

Comment: I see. Should each call of `sys_guess` give me a different value though? They're all in the same method and I'd figured it would keep its value all the way through until it was called explicitly or something. Do I store `sys_guess`s value into another variable?

Comment: You do call it explicitly, several times. The easiest fix is to store the result of call to `sys_guess` in a variable. `sg = sys_guess` or something, and then use `sg` in your lookups and comparisons.